# Find the index of the next empty row inside of a loop ( VB Excel )

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet full of data sections, each data section is separated by an empty row.

While I'm looping over each row of the worksheet, I need to find the index of the next blank row so I can know where the current data section ends & apply modifications to it before passing to the next data section.

Here is an example of my first loop (inside this loop I need to find the index of the next blank row):

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row    

Range("A1").Select
For x = 1 To lastrow
    If Left(Cells(x, "A").Value, 8) = "!JOURNAL" And Not (IsEmpty(Cells(x, "H"))) Then
          
'''Here I need to add another loop to find the index of my next blank row please'''
            idxblankrow = Range(Cells(x, "A")).CurrentRegion.Row
            MsgBox "Idx blank row is " & idxblkrow
            Range(Cells(x + 2, "A"), Cells(idxblankrow - 1, "H")).Cut Range(Cells(x + 2, "B"), Cells(idxblankrow - 1, "I"))
            Range(Cells(x, "H")).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Range(Cells(x + 2, "A"), Cells(idxblankrow - 1, "A")).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    Next
```

Here is another failed attempt(the second nest For loop is what tries to search for the blank row):

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 
   
For x = 1 To lastrow
    If Left(Cells(x, "A").Value, 8) = "!JOURNAL" And Not (IsEmpty(Cells(x, "H"))) Then
        For j = x To lastrow
            If IsEmpty(Cells(j, "A")) Then idxblankrow = Cells(j, "A").Row
            MsgBox "blank row " & idxblankrow
                Exit For
            End If
                        
        
        Range(Cells(x + 2, "A"), Cells(idxblankrow - 1, "H")).Cut Range(Cells(x + 2, "B"), Cells(idxblankrow - 1, "I"))
        Range(Cells(x, "H")).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range(Cells(x + 2, "A"), Cells(idxblankrow - 1, "A")).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
Next
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need the "next empty row"? Your code determines **the LAST empty row** (`lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row   `)... If you wand doing anything else if the cell in A:A is empty, it should be enough to check that `ElseIf Cells(x, "A").value = "" Then` and do what you need. If not clear what I suggested, or it looks not suitable for you, please better explain what you try accomplishing. I mean, globally. Maybe I am missing something... Even if I think the way I understand the shown code must run as you need using my suggestion. This looks as a "XY" question to me...

Comment: My code determines the last empty row of the whole worksheet which is needed to loop over all the rows, but then I need the find the index of every next blank row to determines where the current data section ends ... I hope I explained a bit better now

Comment: Would something like this work : ''' Range(Cells(currentrow, column)).End(xldown).row " ? would it return the index of the next blank row in the section ?

Comment: But, what I suggested does exactly what you need... `ElseIf Cells(x, "A").value = "" Then`. Here is the next empty row. After it you may try another approach, according to your iteration logic, or continue it. `Cells(lastRow + 1, "A").End(xlDown).row` will return the next empty row. But why do you need that, since your iteration continues?

Comment: But I need to use the index of the next blank row INSIDE my 'IF statement' ... what you suggested gives it afterwards. I updated my code, maybe it's more clear now

Comment: I cannot understand your added code. Please, explain **in words** what you try accomplishing. Or confirm my supposition: Do you want cutting the range starting from `Range("A" & x +2)` up to column "H" jut above the first empty row and paste it starting from `Range("B" & x +2)` ? Do you also try something else? If so, please explain **in words** what you try accomplishing. Do you try copying `Cell(x, "H")` own the column A:A, starting from `Cells(x + 2, "A")` up to the first empty row - 1? (All that in A:A?

Comment: Exactly ! Your supposition is what I'm trying to do but I need the index of the blank row to do that

Comment: Then, try the updated code I posted and send some feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use the next adapted way. It does  not select, it does not use clipboard:

```
For x = 1 To LastRow
    If left(cells(x, "A").Value, 8) = "!JOURNAL" And Not (IsEmpty(cells(x, "H"))) Then
          
            idxblankrow = cells(x, "A").End(xlDown).Row
            MsgBox "Idx blank row is " & idxblankrow 
            Range(cells(x + 2, "A"), cells(idxblankrow - 1, "H")).Cut cells(x + 2, "B")
            'copy the value from "H" on the whole A:A column portion:
            Range("A" & x & ":A" & idxblankrow - 1).Value = cells(x, "H").Value 'not using clipboard...
            
            Stop 'check when stopped here if it did what you need
                 'if so, please press F5 to continue and check again.
            
            'you probably need to increment x to continue iteration after the processed portion
            'something as:
            x = x + (idxblankrow - x) + 2 '???
        End If
Next x
```

You probably need now to increment x with the number of rows which have been processed, but **you** must explain **in words** what you try accomplishing. Guessing is not an appropriate way of working here...

Comment: @Keyser Soze Since you do not clarify what I asked for, please try the updated code. I tried incrementing `x` to make iteration jumping to the next range portion. But, if you do not explain in words what you try accomplishing it is only a logical guess...

Comment: @Keyser Glad I could (finally) help! But you must learn that not explaining what you try accomplishing and only showing a not working piece of code, it is very difficult to be helped only Guessing what you need...

Comment: My other comment was to make the OP aware that the  "data section" must be 2 or more lines for the `End(xlDown)` to work.

Answer (score 1):

If I want to know if an entire row is empty, I just concatenate the whole row and check the length. If this is zero, then the row is blank. Else, it's not.

See following exemplary screenshot (only the fourth row is empty, which is seen in the fourth formula, giving zero as a result):

[image]

Comment: I already know my rows are fully empty, what I really need is a method that return the INDEX of the empty row for my current REGION (or data section as I named it)

Comment: In your screenshot for example, a region for me is the lines 1,2,3 separated by a blank then lines 5,6 are another region separated by two blank rows then lines 9,...,14

Comment: I updated my post adding a failed attempt if you would check it out please

Answer (score 1):

Use flags to identify the start and end of the group. This deals with multiple blank rows between groups.

```
Sub macro()

   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, n As Long
   Dim x As Long, z As Long
   Dim bStart As Boolean, bEnd As Boolean
   
   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
   n = 0
   With ws
       lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
       For i = 1 To lastrow
       
            ' start of group
            If Len(.Cells(i, "A")) > 0 Then
                bStart = True
                n = n + 1
            End If
            
            ' end of group look ahead
            If Len(.Cells(i + 1, "A")) = 0 Then
                bEnd = bStart
            End If
            
            ' valid range
            If bStart And bEnd Then
                x = i - n + 1 ' first row of group
                MsgBox "Processing rows " & x & " to " & i
                
                If Left(.Cells(x, "A").Value, 8) = "!JOURNAL" _
                    And Not (IsEmpty(Cells(x, "H"))) Then
                        ' process rows x to i
                End If
                ' reset flags
                n = 0
                bStart = False
                bEnd = False
            End If
                    
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

All these answers could be much simpler. Consider this:

```
iNextBlankRow = Sheet1.Range("A" & iNextBlankRow & ":A50").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells(1, 1).Row
```

To demonstrate, run this macro:

```
Sub BlankRowTest()
    Dim iNextBlankRow As Long
    Dim r As Long
    
    iNextBlankRow = 1
    For r = 1 To 50
        If iNextBlankRow <= r Then iNextBlankRow = Sheet1.Range("A" & iNextBlankRow + 1 & ":A50").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells(1, 1).Row
        Debug.Print r, iNextBlankRow, "'" & Sheet1.Cells(r, 1).Value & "'"
    Next
End Sub
```

This code loops through the first 50 rows looking for the next blank row. When it finds it, it assigns it to the variable iNextBlankRow. We don't bother updating that until our current row (r) is greater than or equal to INextBlankRow. At that point we look again starting from the next row.

Comment: `Sheet1.Cells(x, 1).Value` what is x ?

Comment: Oops. Decided after pasting the code into the editor that r made more sense for a row variable than the x I originally used. Thanks for catching that.